# How can i make Standard ASCII folding analyzer work with suggestions?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am creating an Index in Azure Search and when defining the fields, i have some fields liKE Country, Subdivision, Municipality..., that basically are locations to suggest. But an spanish user for example doesn't need to know how to writte this special characters for "7ème Arrondissement" for example in French or "Linnanmäki", so i guess i need to change the analyzer to Standard Ascii folding.Is this correct? But when creating the index i get an error that is not supported this analyzer with suggestions in this version of the API, only standard analyzer. How can i fix this? Can i change the API version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a bit of investigation i think that there is no posible. A solution for someone with the same issue would be to apply ASCII folding at the moment of inserting in the index or database and convert everything to english characters. Is what i will do.